# What's the root of my android app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a simple android app. I want to know if an image exist in one of my apps' folder, but I don't know what's the root of my app. I tried...

```
File nomeFile = new File("res/drawable-hdpi/imagename.jpg")
File nomeFile = new File("myappanem/res/drawable-hdpi/imagename.jpg")
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant access drawable or manifest after packaging. because there will be no "drawable" folder or manifest file at all. All your drawables packed in APK file after installation. You cant reach them.
But you can access any folder of your phone in your app like that.

Firstly make directory.

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator  
+"Your folder");
  directory.mkdirs();
```

Access your folder like that.

```
 String fileUrl = "/Your folder/a.png";

 String file = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +  
 fileUrl;
File f = new File(file);
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. But i still have a problem understanding. I need to know how to get to my apk root; so i can reach my file. For instance, I tried to reach the AndroidManifest.xml, that is in the root of my apk. I used all the codes you suggest me, and then i added the string "/AndroidManifest.xml". But when i check if that file exist (with filename.exist()), android tell me it doesnt'.

Comment: thank you. Now I have to explain better what I have to do.
My app need to use some images, taking them from a folder, without knowing their name or how many they are.

According to what you said, I have first to create a folder on the mobile, then I have to copy in that folder the images I want to use later?

Comment: yes, i want to "manage" the images in a folder; i want to know their name, how many they are, i want display them etc.

So, i supposed,  i have to copy those images from my apk (?) to the mobile phone, and then reach them!

I have to put those images on the phone, i can't use some images that are already on the phone

Comment: Thank you. I'll study downloadmanager, I'm a very beginner java & android student, so I have to study it. 

Actually i'm wondering if I can do what I want to do in a easier and more correct way.

I'm trying to create a very simple (and stupid) game. I create a random number, and then i show a pic.
For example, if the number is 1, I show 1.jpg. Should i copy the images to the mobile phone to do it? According to what I understood, I can't reach dynamically images in my apk. Can I?
Thank you, you're very kind and helpful

Comment: sorry, actually i already did it. I wrote on this forum because, according to what i want to do, I don't know how many pics i might have! I would like to know how many pic i have in my apk folder, so i can create a random number related to the number of images.
I had problem when trying to know how many images i have in my apk  and when putting togheter R.drawable. and the randomNumeber variable.
I could solve the first problem with a variable, so i can create a random number related to the variable value. But i couldn't solve the secondo problem  (R.drawable. + randomNumeberVariable)

Comment: Put images on your drawble folder and randomly generate pics like that .Above your onCreate ( private int[] mPhotoIds = new int [] { R.drawable.main, R.drawable.ma, R.drawable.mai, R.drawable.mi, R.drawable.m };)  And in your onCreate (Integer q = mPhotoIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mPhotoIds.length)];
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main);
        iv.setImageResource(q);
 private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();  ).

Comment: I put images i my  drawble folder, How can I generate pics randomly ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
File YourFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Android/data/....yourfile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. But i still have a problem understanding. I need to know how to get to my apk root; so i can reach my file. For instance, I tried to reach the AndroidManifest.xml, that is in the root of my apk. I used all the codes you suggest me, and then i added the string "/AndroidManifest.xml". But when i check if that file exist (with filename.exist()), android tell me it doesnt'.

Answer (score 0):

whether your taking about internal memory of your application cache directory 
     //use this for internal memory

```
     String path =Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File myImage=new File(path,"your file name.extension");

     //use this for cache directory     

    String path=getApplicationContext().getDir("" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File myImage=new File(path,"your file name.extension")
```

Comment: Thanks everybody.

But i still have a problem understanding. I need to know how to get to my apk root; so i can reach my file.

For instance, I tried to reach the AndroidManifest.xml, that is in the root of my apk.
I used all the codes you suggest me, and then i added the string "/AndroidManifest.xml".
But when i check if that file exist (with filename.exist()), android tell me it doesnt'.

Comment: you need to root your device